# How to add two styles in react?

Tags: reactjs

i need to give two class Name when i give

```
       <p
            className={Styles.headerbtn, Styles.headerbtnchat}
            disableElevation
          >
            <img src="/assets/images/Chat_Bubble.png" alt="" />
            <span className={Styles.headerbtntxt}>Chat us</span>
          </p>
```

like this it shows some error.

Im trying to multiple classname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `className` prop accepts a string as input.

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string interpolation.

`` className={`${Styles.headerbtn} ${Styles.headerbtnchat}`} ``

This way, if you wanted to add more classnames that are not variables you could write it like:
`` className={`another_class ${Styles.headerbtn} ${Styles.headerbtnchat}`} ``

Or look at special libraries e.g. [classnames](https://jedwatson.github.io/classnames/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this library [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and try like this,

```
 <p
        className={classNames(classes.headerbtn, classes.headerbtnchat)}
        disableElevation
      >
        <img src="/assets/images/Chat_Bubble.png" alt="" />
        <span className={Styles.headerbtntxt}>Chat us</span>
      </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update code with the following snippets

```
   <p className={Styles.headerbtn + ' ' + Styles.headerbtnchat}
     disableElevation>
      <img src="/assets/images/Chat_Bubble.png" alt="" />
       <span className={Styles.headerbtntxt}>Chat us</span>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
className={`${Styles.headerbtn} ${Styles.headerbtnchat}`}
```